# Add prefix to start of every line doesnt work

Tags: python

I have a line a script that grabs all .blend files in a directory and subdirectories and writes their path into a file. I want every single line to have a starting prefix that is

> "

But it doesn't work. It works when I add a prefix to the end of the line which I also need.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.blend'):
                    with open("filepaths","a+") as f:
                        f.write(os.path.join('"', root, file, '",' "\n"))
```

This outputs

`/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/splash279.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/lib/props/barbershop_pole.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/lib/props/hairdryer.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/lib/chars/pigeon.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/lib/chars/agent.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/lib/nodes/nodes_shaders.blend/",
/home/django/copypaste/cleanup/var/media/admin/94bbcd25-10a2-4ec2-bd83-a7cef0690320/splash279/tools/camera_rig.blend/",`

But it is missing the first prefix of `"` at the start of the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
f.write(f'"{os.path.join(root, file)}",\n'))           # python 3.6+
f.write('"{}",\n'.format(os.path.join(root, file))))   # python 2.7+
```

Test:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for file in files:
        # if file.endswith('.blend'): # have no blends
        with open("filepaths","a+") as f:
            f.write(f'"{os.path.join(root, file)}",\n')            # 3.6
            f.write('"{}",\n'.format(os.path.join(root, file)))    # 2.7

with open("filepaths" ) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output (only got a single file in dir, writing it twice (3.6 + 2.7) to file ):

```
"./main.py",
"./main.py",
```

---

No idea why yours does not work though ... this works in 3.6:

```
import os
for i in range(5):
    with open(f"{i}.blend","w") as f:
        f.write(" ")
    with open(f"{i}.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(" ")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.blend'):
            with open("filepaths","a+") as f:
                f.write(os.path.join('"', root, file, '",' "\n"))
        else:
            print("Not a blend: ", file)

with open("filepaths") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
Not a blend:  0.txt
Not a blend:  main.py
Not a blend:  1.txt
Not a blend:  4.txt
Not a blend:  3.txt
Not a blend:  2.txt
"/./3.blend/",
"/./2.blend/",
"/./4.blend/",
"/./1.blend/",
"/./0.blend/",
```

Comment: f.write(f'"{os.path.join(root, file)}",\n'))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @LesnieSncheider try the 2.7 one

Comment: I'm using 3.6.7

Comment: I'm receiving invalid syntax on both examples.

Comment: @LesnieSncheider  the error is elsewhere then ... probably some missing : or ) north of where you think it is. You can copy my example into https://pyfiddle.io/  (put it to 3.6) and it works

Comment: You're right. I removed my ident and saved, added the indent again and saved. Now it doesn't complain anymore and it works. Thank you so much for the help, kind sir!